# Creating an API server with PHP that gets certain data from another api ( Example: api.themoviedb.org)

Tags: php, json, server, api-design

I am creating an API that is used to get certain data (like certain movies from api.themoviedb.org) and then I need to return this data as a JSON object. I was wondering if anyone had some input on how I could go about this as I am lost.

I understand I need to make a GET request from my api, to the public api, with certain search criteria and obviously an api key. I then need to return this data back to the user that made the search request.

Any suggestions with how to go about this please?

Comment: Using AJAX could be one possible way... But-- there are tons of examples and also tutorial across the internet - You might do a proper research first and come back with **code** and **specific issues**

Comment: You basically have it covered. Just remember that your API(script) is just another script. It can do multiple things like call another API, fetch and manipulate data returned from the other API, and then return data to its own caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just design your API as you would normally do, I mean the endpoints, routing, output format, etc.

For the data retrieval from other network resources you can use:

- [php `curl`
  wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php#refsect1-function.curl-init-examples) (preferably)

```php
<?php
$postData = 'whatever';
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Auth: depends-on-your-api',
];
$ch = curl_init("http://your-remote-api.url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// for POST request:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
// end for POST request

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$apiResponseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

- [`file_get_contents` / `fopen` with preset stream
  context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#refsect1-function.stream-context-create-examples)

```php
<?php    
$postData = 'whatever';
$contextData = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header'=> "Content-type: application/json\r\n"
            . "Auth: depends-on-your-api\r\n",
        'content' => $postData
    ]
];
$response = file_get_contents(
    'http://your-remote-api.url',
    false,
    stream_context_create($contextData)
);
```

The links target to specific parts of PHP documentation, that can hint on how to proceed farther.

Comment: I see I see, thanks a lot. Would the user specific requests then also go in the url to the remote api I take it?

Comment: @James In case you need to retrieve user specific data from the remote API then yes. If you can serve them without querying the API then perhaps not. Depends on what you mean by 'user specific'.

Comment: User specific such as searching for a specific movie from tmdb with the movie title or perhaps getting multiple movies released in a certain period of time. This would all come for querying the remote api with their requests and I would hence, add the requests in the correct format to the remote api url (in a way the remote api accepts and deals  with these requests of course)

Comment: @James Yes, then you need to query the _remote_ API for individual user request to _your_ API.